# Need to move three span on the top left of the image

Tags: html, css

[Bestseller, new and trending spans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3qbb.png)

```html
<style>
  .ProductItem__Wrapper {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .ProductItem__Wrapper span.ProductItem__Label {
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #00000029;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 12px!important;
    color: #a85e2f;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<div class="ProductItem__Wrapper">



  <a href="/collections/all/products/microdetox-face-wash" class="ProductItem__ImageWrapper ">
    <div class="AspectRatio AspectRatio--withFallback">



      <img class="spf-product-card__image spf-product-card__image-main lazyautosizes lazyloaded" srcset="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_180x.jpg?v=1647878853 180w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_360x.jpg?v=1647878853 360w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_540x.jpg?v=1647878853 540w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_720x.jpg?v=1647878853 720w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_900x.jpg?v=1647878853 900w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_1080x.jpg?v=1647878853 1080w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_1296x.jpg?v=1647878853 1296w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_1512x.jpg?v=1647878853 1512w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_1728x.jpg?v=1647878853 1728w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_1944x.jpg?v=1647878853 1944w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_2160x.jpg?v=1647878853 2160w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_2376x.jpg?v=1647878853 2376w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_2592x.jpg?v=1647878853 2592w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_2808x.jpg?v=1647878853 2808w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_3024x.jpg?v=1647878853 3024w">



      <span class="Image__Loader"></span>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="ProductItem__LabelList">


  </div>

  <span class="ProductItem__Label Heading Text--subdued newgreentag"> Bestseller</span>

  <span class="ProductItem__Label Heading Text--subdued newbluetag"> New</span>


  <span class="ProductItem__Label Heading Text--subdued newredtag"> Trending</span>


</div>
```

I need in percentage because of the responsive design

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer {
position: relative;
}
.ProductItem__Wrapper { position: relative; } 
.ProductItem__LabelList {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: 999;
}   
.ProductItem__Wrapper span.ProductItem__Label { 
box-shadow: 0 0 6px #00000029; 
position: relative; top: 50%; 
left: 5px; 
font-size: 12px!important; 
color: #a85e2f; 
padding: 2px 8px; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="outer">


<a href="/collections/all/products/microdetox-face-wash" class="ProductItem__ImageWrapper ">
  <div class="AspectRatio AspectRatio--withFallback"
     >



      <img class="spf-product-card__image spf-product-card__image-main lazyautosizes lazyloaded"
          srcset="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_180x.jpg?v=1647878853 180w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_360x.jpg?v=1647878853 360w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_540x.jpg?v=1647878853 540w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_720x.jpg?v=1647878853 720w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_900x.jpg?v=1647878853 900w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_1080x.jpg?v=1647878853 1080w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_1296x.jpg?v=1647878853 1296w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_1512x.jpg?v=1647878853 1512w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_1728x.jpg?v=1647878853 1728w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_1944x.jpg?v=1647878853 1944w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_2160x.jpg?v=1647878853 2160w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_2376x.jpg?v=1647878853 2376w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_2592x.jpg?v=1647878853 2592w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_2808x.jpg?v=1647878853 2808w, https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0578/2480/5033/products/StudioSession-761-min_3024x.jpg?v=1647878853 3024w"
         >



      <span class="Image__Loader"></span>
  </div>
</a>
<div class="ProductItem__LabelList">


<span class="ProductItem__Label Heading Text--subdued newgreentag"> Bestseller</span>

<span class="ProductItem__Label Heading Text--subdued newbluetag"> New</span>


<span class="ProductItem__Label Heading Text--subdued newredtag"> Trending</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Not working the theme - https://gzykba8mily7k343-57824805033.shopifypreview.com - please go to collection/all

Comment: Hi! i have just checked this link https://gzykba8mily7k343-57824805033.shopifypreview.com/collections/all  its working